# Link/Hyperlink to be Open in New tab?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, links-list

How can I set to **open some particular links in new tab(by default)** from Global Navigation bar and Link from Link List app.

Comment: Please be more clear- you mean Site settings global navigation

Comment: I mean links in the  global Navigation bar at home page of any page as well as links with in the **Link List  Web App**

Comment: is it publishing site? in Global Navigation Bar means, link to subsite or pages on top right?

Answer (score 3):

Write a script to with quoting classnames.
get the classname where ever u want to apply this.

Here is the example

```
$(function () {    
    $(".classname a").each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('_target', "blank");
    });
});
```

Load this script into master page.

Answer (score 3):

This [article](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/02/sharepoint-link-list-open-in-new-window_21.html) describes an old trick for making certain links open in a new tab.  Just append the url for any link you want to open in a new tab with `#openinnewtab`, and add the following javascript code (master page would be best):

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('a[href$="#openinnewtab"]').attr('target', '_blank'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy OOTB approach is to edit the page, select the Link tab in the ribbon, check the "open in new tab" box next to the URL.  Not sure for a links web part, but you can do the same config in a Custom Links web part.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could specify `target='_blank'` in the `<a>` tag. Please refer the [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/99e9559a-da76-4722-982c-882b3e4181c7/deleted?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) for details:

Comment: Your answer provides a correct solution to open links in a new tab, however, you should include for the operator information on how to inject the global navigation bar with your Code.