# How to set links to "Open in new tab" by default?

Tags: 2010, hyperlink

SharePoint is *smart* enough to recognize links when typed or pasted into a wiki page as it hyperlinks it automatically. Similarly, when *inserting* links a dialog appears with text to display and the address.

The problem is every link (except wiki links) opens in the same window/tab. There is an option under the **Link Tools** > **Format** ribbon (it's contextual when the cursor is *within* a hyperlink) when you may check **Open in a new tab** in the **Behavior** group.

[image: SharePoint Link Tools Format Behavior Open in new tab checkbox]

> Is there a way to have that checked by default when adding non-wiki links to a page?

I have seen other solutions using JavaScript and JQuery to manipulate the DOM and set the `target=_blank` attribute (see [Link/Hyperlink to be Open in New tab?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/142709)). I am looking for **an OOTB solution** if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, if I set a link to open in new tab using "Open in new tab" and save the page, when i click the link, it will be opened in a new tab.

For your issue, please make sure you have selected the link then set it to "open in new tab".

In addition, my SharePoint 2010 is 14.0.7175.5000, you can check your build number of your SharePoint 2010 farm.

Comment: When it is checked, it works as expected: opening in a new tab/window (pending on the browser). My issue is that this box needs to be checked _every_ time a hyperlink is created. I want that option checked by default.

Comment: No, there is no OOB way to set a link to open in a new tab except "Open in new tab" option.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a site collection or farm setting to give that behaviour. That is unfortunate.